# spring security 4 RestController with ldap provider

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, ldap

I am trying to build a `@Restcontroller` with some basic function and authenticate/authorize thru spring security 4 with an ldap backend, all in java config. I have some questions:

- storing passwords in ldap are realworld scenarios or they should be somewhere in a database and that involves a custom `userDetailService` implementation with dao functions?
- If passwords should be stored in ldap then `PasswordComparisonAuthenticator` is how performance optimized(speed, constant connection toward ldap)?
- When calling the `@RestController` how should the caller authenticate and what java config needs to be done there?

My current implementation works with simple httpBasic authentication against the `@RestController` but when changing the `authenticationProvider` to ldap I get some error(I see the bad credentials error but i don't know why I gets it), am I missing some conceptual thing?:

```
Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'jfryer'
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-3 04:06:02] (ProviderManager.java:authenticate:162) Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-3 04:06:02] (AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:authenticate:67) Processing authentication request for user: jfryer
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-3 04:06:02] (BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:doFilterInternal:196) Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-3 04:06:02] (DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:commence:78) Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-3 04:06:02] (DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:commence:91) No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@56f05ca6
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-3 04:06:02] (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:doFilter:105) SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

And the java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("my packages")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://localhost:11389/o=sevenSeas");
        contextSource.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        contextSource.setPassword("admin");
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordComparisonAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource) {
        PasswordComparisonAuthenticator authenticator = new PasswordComparisonAuthenticator(contextSource);
        String[] userDn = {"cn={0},ou=people"}; 
        authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(userDn);
        authenticator.setPasswordAttributeName("userPassword");
        authenticator.setPasswordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticator;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource) {
        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator populator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, "ou=groups");
        populator.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
        return populator;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource) {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(this.ldapAuthenticator(contextSource), authoritiesPopulator(contextSource));
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource) throws Exception {
        //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider(contextSource));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello/**").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/date/**").hasRole("USER").and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationHandler()).accessDeniedHandler(new PermissionHandler());
    }
}
```

The calling code:

```
    final String helloUri = "http://localhost:8080/Security/hello/Zoltan";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        String auth = "jfryer:alma";
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
        String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
        headers.add("Authorization", authHeader);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(helloUri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: What do you think bad credentials are? Are you sure your ldap configuration is correct? You expect that your passwords are SHA encoded in LDAP are they? Does your user actually exists with the given password in LDAP? Does your LDAP query match.

Comment: I realized that PasswordComparisonAuthenticator is really frigid so I changed to BindAuthenticator. Therefore I do not need admin priviliages to read password attributes only a bind operation is enough. The setUserDnPatterns is a little ambigous, it needs a String array instead of just a String. It can bind to any pattern?